# ufw blocking ssh until "allow outgoing"

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-20.04, ufw

On my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, I have ufw enabled and allowing ssh connections.

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

However, I get a timeout when trying to connect.

But if I then do the following:

```
sudo ufw default allow outgoing  # deny outgoing also works, I've discovered
```

it immediately starts accepting my connection.  This is confusing to me -- it seems like just running some ufw command kicks the firewall into allowing incoming connections.

This is unfortunately not workable, as the state is not persisted across a reboot -- so I cannot use the computer remotely yet: I have to redo the `sudo ufw default allow outgoing` from the local terminal after restart.

I have tried purging and re-installing ufw.  I'm interested in understanding where to look to figure out why the firewall does not allow ssh, even when the status indicates it should.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with incoming and outgoing traffic.
Check the output of the command `ufw status verbose`:

> Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)

This would deny **any** incoming traffic, including your `ssh`

Here is the solution for your case

```
sudo ufw allow incoming
sudo ufw allow outgoing
sudo ufw allow from (your rules here)
sudo ufw limit ssh (if you want to be safe)
sudo ufw deny from any
```

Either deny `incoming` or `outgoing` would result in a denial of `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

I never was able to solve the problem, but did come up with a workaround.  I created a start-up script to run the no-op (since it is already the setting) `ufw default allow outgoing`.  This seems to kick the firewall into accepting incoming connections.

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/ping-ufw.sh
#!/bin/bash

ufw default allow outgoing >> /root/ping-ufw.out
```

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/ping-ufw.service
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ping-ufw.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable ping-ufw.service
```